# console displays error: class, interface, or enum expected package ball; on run. How do I fix it?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a mini tennis game. I am still a Java beginner and to make the program more organized I tried to create a package of each java file. Once I added the `package` extension and try to run the program the console displays `error: class, interface, or enum expected` on both the `ball` and `racquet` packages. How do I solve this problem?

```
/*This is Package minitennis*/
package minitennis;
package ball;
package racquet;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {

    Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    Racquet racquet = new Racquet(this);

    public Game() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                racquet.keyReleased(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                racquet.keyPressed(e);
            }
        });
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    private void move() {
        ball.move();
        racquet.move();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);
        racquet.paint(g2d);
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.exit(ABORT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            game.move();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }



/*This is Package ball*/
package ball;
package minitennis;
package racquet;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Ball {
    private static final int DIAMETER = 30;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xa = 1;
    int ya = 1;
    private Game game;

    public Ball(Game game) {
        this.game= game;
    }

    void move() {
        if (x + xa < 0)
            xa = 1;
        if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - DIAMETER)
            xa = -1;
        if (y + ya < 0)
            ya = 1;
        if (y + ya > game.getHeight() - DIAMETER)
            game.gameOver();
        if (collision()){
            ya = -1;
            y = game.racquet.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
        }
        x = x + xa;
        y = y + ya;
    }

    private boolean collision() {
        return game.racquet.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
    }
}

/*This is package racquet*/
package racquet;
package minitennis;
package ball;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Racquet {
    private static final int Y = 330;
    private static final int WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 10;
    int x = 0;
    int xa = 0;
    private Game game;

    public Racquet(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void move() {
        if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth() - WIDTH)
            x = x + xa;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.fillRect(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        xa = 0;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            xa = -1;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            xa = 1;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public int getTopY() {
        return Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you putting each of your classes in separate folders that has the exact name of the package? Are you adding the package information on the top of the class file **only** for the one package that it's in? Are you properly importing classes from different packages when you use them? Are you perhaps getting this error while **compiling** and not as you mentioned "on run"?

Comment: I get this error when compiling. Each of the classes is in a separate folder with the exact name that the package in the code shows. I don't know if  I am properly importing the packages.

Comment: You should split up your code, so it's obvious that's it not all in just one file. But read my second question again. A class cannot be in two different packages at the same time. I recommend using [Oracle's Java Tutorial for packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

Comment: I used the tutorial on packages and it really helped, the program is now capable of compiling. Thanks a lot.